# mPDF, remove encoding software

Tags: mpdf

When a PDF file is created by mPDF the encoding software tag is filled with e.g. "mPDF 7.1.9". Thats a security issue.

It is possible to remove the version of mPDF at least?

Thx!

Comment: Can't answer your question but why do you believe that is a security issue?

Comment: Information such as version numbers, software or technology used, names of files or directories, names or abbreviations of developers or other employees, stack traces 
and so on could be enough for attackers in gathering information to prepare effective attacks against systems.

Just imagine a security issue in the used version of mPDF ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'exposeVersion' => false,
]);

// or

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->exposeVersion = false;
```

This, as many other questions, is answered in the documentation, see https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/exposeversion.html

Comment: Thx a lot. I looked for something like hideVersion, removeVersion ;-)

So I have to update mPDF, cause version 7.x doesn't support this variable.